# How to add a piece of code in the same pace in all the files within a folder in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to add this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iehacks.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

to all the files in a folder right before the `</head>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would record a macro to insert the text, then do a :bufdo to apply it to all open files.

Example: 
Open all files in vim, then record a macro in register x with `qx`, go to the top of the file with `gg`, search for the end of the head-tag with `/\/head`, open a line before that with `O` (big O), then type or paste your text as usual, write your file with `:w`, end the recording with `q`.

After that, run `:bufdo normal @x` to apply it to all open buffers.

Comment: I'll try that. Can you give me an example?

Comment: So do I do :bufdo after or before?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible with vim, but you can always execute a shell command from it. Both sed and perl can do inplace file edits. Have a look [here](http://idolinux.blogspot.com/2008/08/sed-in-place-edit.html) and [here](http://www.rice.edu/web/perl-edit.html).